# AVPlayerViewController in Navigation Stack Possible?

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avkit

I am working on a production app and I need to use an instance of `AVPlayerViewController` to play videos.

I would like to have a show segue present the controller by pushing it onto the navigation stack. However, this leads to strange behavior, because the user can press the full-screen button on the bottom right corner.

In Full-screen mode, there is a **Done** button which will exit full screen mode, but half the time, when I press **Done**, all of the playback controls disappear except for the scrubber which cannot move. Since I am in a navigation controller, the screen and the player is still there, but the playback controls break sometimes. It seems like the `AVPlayerViewController` is designed only to be presented modally and automatically dismissed with the **Done** button.

I know that in the documentation and example code, the `AVPlayerViewController` is presented modally into Full Screen and the Done button automatically dismisses it for you. But is it possible to push an `AVPlayerViewController` onto the navigation stack, without that strange **Done** button behavior?

Comment: Why would you want to push it onto the stack? It's supposed to be presented modally. If you want other behaviour subclass (no idea how far you'll get) or implement your own view controller.

Comment: @MarkBourke It was unclear in the documentation that the controller could only be presented modally, so I was hoping someone could clarify. Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: @MarkBourke - why do you say that? I mean, granted, from my own experience presenting it modally works much better. But is there documentation somewhere that explains this?